# How can I include special characters in query strings?

Tags: html, url-rewriting

URL `http://localhost/mysite/mypage?param=123` works fine. However, if I want to put some special characters in `param`, like `?`, `/`, `\`, then the URL becomes `http://localhost/mysite/mypage?param=a=?&b=/` or `http://localhost/mysite/mypage?param=http://www.example.com/page2?a=\&b=...` which won't work. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to encode special characters in URLs. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: If you have special characters like " / ? : @ & = + $ #" then you need to use this extended function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: The more valid reference would be MDN, see below... https://stackoverflow.com/a/35377890/147618

Answer (score 18):

You need to encode the query parameters before combining them to form a url. The function needed here is [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).For example,

the url you need to create is:

```
http://localhost/mysite/mypage?param=a=?&b=/
```

Now, assuming that ? and / comes as variables, you need to encode them before putting in the url.
So lets create your url using this function(I am expecting two query parameters):

```
 var q1 = "a=?"; //came from some input or something
    var q2 = "/"; //came from somewhere else

    var faultyUrl =  "http://localhost/mysite/mypage?param="+ q1 +"&b=" + q2; 
// "http://localhost/mysite/mypage?param=a=?&b=/"


    var properUrl =  "http://localhost/mysite/mypage?param="+ encodeURIComponent(q1) +"&b=" + encodeURIComponent(q2); 
//"http://localhost/mysite/mypage?param=a%3D%3F&b=%2F"
```

This function is in basic JS and supported in all the browsers.

Answer (score 8):

Easy way to pass QueryString value with special character using javascript:

```
var newURL=encodeURIComponent(uri);
window.location="/abc/abc?q="+newURL;
```

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript you can use the `encodeURI()` function.

ASP has the `Server.URLEncode()` function.

You can use `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` in .NET.

Comment: in .Net you want to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to use encode special characters, see [this](http://www.eskimo.com/~bloo/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) page for a reference.

If you're using PHP, there's a function to do this, called [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Answer (score 2):

I did below, it works fine.

```
const myQueryParamValue = "You&Me";
const ajaxUrl = "www.example.com/api?searchText="+encodeURIComponent(myQueryParamValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to substitute the characters with URL entities.
[Some information here.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)