# How to retrieve query string value which contains Hash character

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-encoding

In my Asp.net (C#)  application, I need to read three parameters from the query string (Item, Code and Location). Url is given below.

> http://localhost/Reports?ITEM=A#1234&CODE=0013&LOCATION=LOCA#001

I am reading it like this.

```
            _code = Request["CODE"]; //value should be 0013
            _item = Request["ITEM"]; //value should be A#1234
            _location = Request["LOCATION"]; //value should be LOCA#001
```

But after `#` character, nothing retrievable to the variables.
Our database contains lots of data items with hash`(#)` character. Any idea how to read with `#` ?

Comment: Try using encodeURIComponent Refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828211/how-to-include-special-characters-in-query-strings

Answer (score 1):

Use URL encoding for the param values [urlencode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the [WebUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

```
using System;
using System.Net;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            string urlValue = "ITEM="+WebUtility.UrlEncode("A#1234") + "&CODE=0013&LOCATION=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode("LOCA#001");
            Console.WriteLine(urlValue);
            Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.UrlDecode(urlValue));

        }
    }
```