# @RestController @GetMapping does not handle parameter-value with '+'

Tags: java, rest, encoding, spring-restcontroller, get-mapping

My controller-class:

```
@RestController
 @RequestMapping(value = UserRestController.REST_URL, produces = 
 MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserRestController  {

 @GetMapping
public List<User> getByParameter(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {
    logger.info("PARAMETER VALUE " + parameters.get("phone"));
    return service.getByParameter(parameters);
    }

}
```

When I run get-request on

```
http://localhost:8080/test/customers?phone=+78122347389
```

it does not return any result, as it does not see '+'.

Indeed, in log I see:

```
PARAMETER VALUE  78122347389
```

May be problem in encoding?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828211/how-to-include-special-characters-in-query-strings) answers your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I use URLEncoder.encode  to encode param-value from Map<Srring, String> parameters