# AdonisJS doesn't refresh token because Invalid Token

Tags: access-token, refresh-token, jwt, adonis.js

I'm trying to get a new access token sending a post request to server. I'm using postman to send the refresh token and the function that handles this is bellow this paragraph. The server response is E_INVALID_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN

```js
async refresh({
    request,
    response,
    auth
  }) {
     try {
      const refresh_token = request.input('refresh_token')
      const decrypted = Encryption.decrypt(refresh_token)
      console.log(decrypted)
      const token = await auth.generateForRefreshToken(refresh_token, true)
      console.log('Token is',token)
      return response.status(200).json(token)
     } catch (error) {
       return response.status(401).json(error)
     }
  }
```

As you can see, I decrypted the token and it's ok. Also check the database and is ok.

Apparently I'm not the only one that have this error and an issue is closed in GitHub

UPDATE:

This is my config/auth.js

```js
jwt: {
    serializer: 'LucidMongo',
    model: 'App/Models/User',
    scheme: 'jwt',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password',
    options: {
      secret: Env.get('APP_KEY'),
      expiresIn: '60m',
    }
  },
```

Comment: Can you share a sample project so I can reproduce the problem? (with config, ...)

Comment: @CrBast is a complex project but, The simple way to see it is that a send a POST request to the route /auth/refresh - with the variable refresh_token on the body - that calls the method `refresh()` from the AuthController

Answer (score 1):

#### The `+` character is problematic. Errors with this character are common on query string.

If you log the result of `refresh_token` you might notice that the `+` character is replaced by a space.

### Solutions

#### 1. You can use libraries to convert request to a `queryString`

Example with [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string):

```js
var query = queryString.stringify({
  refresh_token:
    "74f7c7e26621d231feb39c4a9c6a76bajOKUVX+J3LG/f4hJQzy3+hgL+p2w0VkRRw6xT/NnVxUofjh/zRVJJyuwGEfoCL+l"
});
```

Ouput (`query`):

```
refresh_token=74f7c7e26621d231feb39c4a9c6a76bajOKUVX%2BJ3LG%2Ff4hJQzy3%2BhgL%2Bp2w0VkRRw6xT%2FNnVxUofjh%2FzRVJJyuwGEfoCL%2Bl
```

#### 2. You can use `Request Body`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body

With this method, there is no need to convert the text

**The best solution will depend on your needs.**

---

### Interesting links

[How to include special characters in query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828211/how-to-include-special-characters-in-query-strings)

[Plus sign in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string)

[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: Thanks! I found a similar answer before so in my case I make a POST request and send the `refresh_token` through the request body. Do you think I have to apply this solution too?

Comment: You're welcome. Your solution is good. You can use both possibilities. It depends on your use.

Comment: I added your solution to my answer. Can you tell me if there are any changes to be made?

Comment: I tried to add this but it gives me the same error. I decrypted the token because I suspected that probably the problem was with the token and it's ok. Now, I don't know what to do

Comment: Can you share your `config/auth.js`? Or you can also create an issue on github (https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-auth) with a test project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done, I added my `config/auth.js` file

Answer (score 0):

That is depends on consensus of the character encoding between client and server you are apply.

eg:

Client:

```
encrypted = toUTF8(Encryption.encrypt(token));
```

Server:

```
decrypted = Encryption.decrypt(fromUTF8(refresh_token))
```

Comment: encryptedUTF8 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(encryptedText); CryptoJS lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js. Or: function Utf8(text) { if (/u0080-\uFFFF/.test(text)) text = unescape(encodeURIComponent(text)); return text; }