# What all special characters that .net core Web API allows

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

> This is POST method Request Body ,where I am trying to send special characters but I am getting error.

```
                {
  
                     "name": "@!#%^#)(?><%$"*",
     
                      "description": "string",

                }
```

> ERROR :

{

"errors":

{

"name": [
"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: *. Path 'name', line 2, position 14."

```
]
```

},

"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",

"status": 400,

}

//This is my Get Method

[HttpGet]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByNameAsync( [FromQuery] string name)
{
_service.GetByName(name)
 return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your name contains double quotes, you need to add `\` before your `"`.

You can try the following Json:

```
{
"name": "@!#%^#)(?><%$\"*",
"description": "string"
}
```

Please use objects to receive parameters in the background.

Class:

```
public class Model
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Post action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody]Model model)
{   
  //...
  return Ok();
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: But what if I want to Use GET by Name  with same special character which I saved .It saying No Records found ,search is not happening .pls help me out

Comment: URL encoding is the way to go.

Comment: I tried with POST Method instead of GET ,Can't We get it through POST

Comment: What is your main problem? Is there no get method to bind successfully?

Comment: I have getByName method to fetch names but wen it comes to special character ,not able to fetch the data.

Comment: Can you share your `getByName` method?

Comment: Posted above ,u can have look on it

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828211/how-can-i-include-special-characters-in-query-strings)