# Calling Codeigniter 4 controller with '+' in parameter value

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to call controller with a parameter having string "10+2", controller printing 10 2 without +

```
public function MyFun($Para)
{
   echo $Para; // 10 2 NOT 10+2
}
```

Comment: `+`  or `%20` stands for a space when your URL params get decoded. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP#:~:text=URLs%20cannot%20contain%20spaces.%20URL%20encoding%20normally%20replaces%20a%20space%20with%20a%20plus%20(%2B)%20sign%20or%20with%20%2520.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I include special characters in query strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828211/how-can-i-include-special-characters-in-query-strings)